# axis2 webservice EPR issue

Tags: web-services, wsdl, apache-axis

So, i've been been trying to deploy a very simple service, following this tutorial using maven3 and Java EE eclilpse

http://maksim.sorokin.dk/it/2011/01/13/axis2-maven-servlets-tomcat/

But receive this exception.

org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The service cannot be found for the endpoint reference (EPR) /axis2Example/services/HelloWs/sayHello?name=Max
 at org.apache.axis2.
...

I'm guessing the service mapping is wrong, and that the service doesn't actually exist at that url, but my understanding of web.xml and services.xml is just too shallow to see where the issue is.

all my config xml's are exactly as described in the tutorial, and the deployed servlet in tomcat/webapps has a folder structure as follows:

```
axis2Example
|   HelloWs.wsdl
|
+---META-INF (also a maven folder with the pom)
|      MANIFEST.MF
\---WEB-INF
    |   web.xml
    |
    +---classes
    |
    +---lib
    |
    +---services
           |
           +---HelloWs
                  |
                  +---META-INF
                         services.xml
```

I've uploaded my war to http://www.mediafire.com/?e8tchhtp4koc1t5

If anyone can take a look I would much appreciate it.  The deadline to ship is actually thursday lawl, can't believe this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to rename the folder under WEB-INF/classes/axis2example to axis2Example (this is how you have given in the services.xml)

you can use WSO2 AS[1] to deploy your services. which gives you a lot of monitoring and administrative features.

[1] http://wso2.org/library/application-server